# pandas DataFrame.replace function broken for datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In pandas v0.17.1 (anaconda python v3.4.3) the replace function on `datetime`  is broken.

I am trying to replace a string value in my `DataFrame` with new value. This `DataFrame` contains multiple columns (including a datatime column).
The [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function fails

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'no':range(4), 'nm':list('abcd'), 'tm':datetime.now()})
>>> df.replace('a', 'A')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/xxx/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
>   line 2061, in _try_coerce_args
>       other = other.astype('i8',copy=False).view('i8') ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/xxx/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
>   line 594, in replace
>       values, _, to_replace, _ = self._try_coerce_args(self.values, to_replace)   File
>   "/home/xxx/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
>   line 2066, in _try_coerce_args
>       raise TypeError TypeError
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/xxx/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py",
>   line 3110, in replace
>       inplace=inplace, regex=regex)   File "/home/xxx/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
>   line 2870, in replace
>       return self.apply('replace', **kwargs)   File "/home/xxx/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
>   line 2823, in apply
>       applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)   File "/home/xxx/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
>   line 607, in replace
>       if not mask.any(): UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mask' referenced before assignment

This same code is working on fine on pandas version 0.16.2.
Is this a confirmed bug?

Comment: yes, this is a bug introduced by https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/2cda5230c72bd9e537f5cf22ef42924bbef3e69e - you may want to open a bug at pandas issue tracker at github

Comment: @cel thanks. I have opened a [bug on issue tracker](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11868).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug-report. :)

Answer (score 2):

As commented, this is fixed in master and will be included in 0.18 (coming soon in January 2016): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11868, and was present in 0.17.1 only.

---

As a workaround (assuming you have no duplicately named columns), the Series replace still works fine in 0.17.1:

```
for c in df.select_dtypes(include=["object"]).columns:
    df[c] = df[c].replace('a', 'A')
```